# Commas for essential appositives – “the subreddit /r/LanguageTechnology”, or “the subreddit, /r/LanguageTechnology”,

Tags: commas, appositives

> The answer is from user YourWelcomeOrMine from the subreddit
>   /r/LanguageTechnology/.

I instinctively wanted to put a comma between “subreddit” and “/r/LanguageTechnology”, but “/r/LanguageTechnology/” is an essential appositive(?), so you don’t put a comma?

I don’t know why I didn’t feel the same way with “user YourWelcomeOrMine”, even though it’s probably the same situation.

Thanks.

Comment: It is the exact same situation. No comma.

Answer (score 1):

To my ear, the difference is that with a comma, it's implied to be the only subreddit.

> The answer is from the subreddit /r/LanguageTechnology/.

There are many subreddits, this particular one is /r/LanguageTechnology/.

> The answer is from the subreddit, /r/LanguageTechnology/.

There is only one subreddit and it happens to be called /r/LanguageTechnology/.

Comment: Yeah, the comma could work if there was only one subreddit. Everyone knows what you’re talking about, so /r/LanguageTechnology/ becomes nonessential.